# Html navigation using drop down menu. Selected value must allways appears at top of the menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Created http://jsfiddle.net/jWwPV/ some kind of drop down menu.

```
<div class="dropdown_navigation_general" style="float:left;" >
    <select name="general_select" id="general_select" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="general">
        <option selected>General</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Add transaction partner</option>
    </select>
</div>

.dropdown_navigation_general {
    margin:auto;
    width:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.dropdown_navigation_general select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    height: 19px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

When I click on `Add transaction partner`, then for a short moment at top of the menu instead of `General` I see `Add transaction partner`.

Is it possible that after clicking any of drop downmenu values at top of the menu I always see `General` (selected value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="general_select" id="general_select"
 onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
 this.value='general'">
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jWwPV/1/